# How can I use the external.IsSearchProviderInstalled function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How is the function `external.IsSearchProviderInstalled` meant to be used? I've tried things like `external.IsSearchProviderInstalled('http://www.google.com')` but I keep getting an `Error` in Chrome?

What is the function `external.IsSearchProviderInstalled`? How should it be used in Chrome?

Comment: It has no support in chrome (http://help.dottoro.com/ljfslnsp.php) - currently.

Comment: Hum, the function does exist...

Comment: I am pretty sure it shows that it isn't supported, shown by a faded chome icon, and when you hover over it, it says clearly that it isn't supported on chome.

Comment: @agam360 That's speculation. It's supposed to be implemented - http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/renderer/external_extension.cc. Visit http://crbug.com/ and open a bug report if it does not already exist yet (I didn't find any).

Comment: @RobW, #@Randomblue, I am sorry, I have no clue now because I've seen that the method does exist via the Console - Anyway good luck.

Comment: Maybe Google did not want it to be implemented to prevent competition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec for IsSearchProviderInstalled is here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/system-state-and-capabilities.html#dom-external-issearchproviderinstalled

The most likely reason you are getting an error is because "Only results pages on the same domain as the script that calls this method are checked."  So you can only check if providers on your domain are installed.

e.g. If you go to https://www.google.com, open the Javascript console and say
`external.IsSearchProviderInstalled('https://www.google.com')` you'll get back a 0, 1 or 2 depending on your search provider settings.

However, if you try the same call on a different domain, an Error is thrown.  It is a poorly defined generic error, but there is a FIXME in the Chromium code to respond with something more descriptive (c.f. ExternalExtensionWrapper::IsSearchProviderInstalled in src/chrome/renderer/external_extension.cc)